# Facebook app shuts down itself on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, applications, ios, facebook

I have an iPhone 4. The Facebook application was working fine until this morning. When I start the Facebook app, it shuts down immediately. I tried restarting the phone but it's the same. No jailbreak, no unlock. My phone is 9 months old.

Comment: BTW it's the last version of Facebook: 4.1 and iOS 5.1

Comment: The iPhone 4S is less than 9 months old. Do you have an iPhone 4?

Comment: @bneely The title was originally right. It is an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try uninstalling the app, restarting your phone, and reinstalling it from the App Store. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: I just reinstalled the app and it worked, no need to restart the phone. Any clue about why did this happen?

Comment: It was probably a corrupt plist. Since the OS is closed, you can't remove just the plist and restart the app. You have to remove the whole app and reinstall. A little cumbersome, but effective.

Comment: Same thing worked when I had (numerous) issues with the NYTimes app.